# Unable to add classpath in Android studio chipMunk

Tags: android

I updated android studio to chipMunk where classpath is not visible in project level build.gradle. where I need to add classpath. what's alternate to classpath in chipmunk and latest android studio?

Answer (score 1):

On top of your build.gradle (in root) you can find **buildscript**. If not exist in your build gradle just add it.
It should look like this:

```
buildscript {
 ext { ... }

 dependencies {
    classpath "your package with verion"
 }
}
```