# Where to put Android Gradle Plugin version in the new Android Studio (Bumblebee and above) Gradle setup?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When you are creating new Android project with the latest version of Android Studio it will now give you a project level `build.gradle` that only contains plugins block

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

My question is how to specify now the version of AGP with this setup? Before it looks like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    // This block encapsulates custom properties and makes them available to all modules in the project.
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.20-M1'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-alpha03'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}
```

I also wonder how would you add classpath on some plugins that still requires it like

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

What I also do not understand is what does `com.android.library` plugin do and why is it in app module?

Another thing to ask is with this new setup you have two plugins block, one in app level and one in project level. Is this really necessary? What is the point of that? Thanks

Comment: I think this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318007/unable-to-add-classpath-in-android-studio-chipmunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new Gradle [setup](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) is called `plugins DSL`, it is the new way to add Gradle plugin dependency without needing to add its `classpath`. While the old [legacy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) way requires you to include the dependency's classpath inside the `buildscript` block.

Note that some of the plugins like `com.google.gms:google-services:${version}` still not support the new plugin DSL and you are required to add `buildscript` using the legacy approach.

Answer (score 0):

You hould put it in project level `build.gradle` file like this

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
}}
```